# MySQL Queries taking too long to load

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have a database table, with 300,000 rows and 113.7 MB in size. I have my database running on Ubuntu 13.10 with 8 Cores and 8GB of RAM. As things are now, the MySQL server uses up an average of 750% CPU. and 6.5 %MEM (results obtained by running `top` in the CLI). Also to note, it runs on the same server as Apache2 Web Server.

Here's what I get on the Mem line:
`Mem:   8141292k total,  6938244k used,  1203048k free,   211396k buffers`

When I run: `show processlist;` I get something like this in return:

```
2098812 | admin | localhost       | phpb | Query   |   12 | Sending data | SELECT * FROM items WHERE thumb = 'Halloween 2013 Horns/thumbs/Halloween 2013 Horns (Original).png'
2098813 | admin | localhost       | phpb | Query   |   12 | Sending data | SELECT * FROM items WHERE thumb = 'Halloween 2013 Witch Hat/thumbs/Halloween 2013 Witch Hat (Origina
2098814 | admin | localhost       | phpb | Query   |   12 | Sending data | SELECT * FROM items WHERE thumb = 'Halloween 2013 Blouse/thumbs/Halloween 2013 Blouse (Original).png
2098818 | admin | localhost       | phpb | Query   |   11 | Sending data | SELECT * FROM items WHERE parent = 210162 OR auto = 210162
```

Some queries are taking an excess of 10 seconds to execute, this is not the top of the list, but somewhere in the middle just to give kind of a perspective of how many queries are stacking up in this list. I feel that it may have something to do with my Query Cash configurations. Here are the configurations show from running the `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qc%';`

```
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 434      |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 2037880  |
| Qcache_hits             | 62580686 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 10865474 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 4157011  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 3140518  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 1260     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 4440     |
+-------------------------+----------+
```

I noticed that the `Qcache_lowmem_prunes` seem a bit high, is this normal?

I've been searching around StackOverflow, but I couldn't find anything that would solve my problem. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Maybe, you'll be luckier with this kind of question at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: DO you have indexes on your tables?

Comment: I will post it there as well, thank you Louis.
And yes, I do have indexes.

Comment: Have you put indexes on your tables? Maybe you should select some of these queries and examine the execution plan via EXPLAIN.

Comment: Execute those last 2 queries in your list with `explain` before them.

Comment: If most of the processes are in `Sending data` state, it doesn't seem like the problem is query efficiency.

Comment: Wouldn't `dba.stackexchange.com` be even better than serverfault?

Answer (score -1):

This is probably one for http://dba.stackexchange.com. That said...

- Why are your queries running slow? Do they return a large result set, or are they just really complex?
- Have you tried running one of these queries using `EXPLAIN SELECT column FROM ...`?
- Are you using indexes correctly?
- How have you configured MySQL in your my.cnf file?
- What table types are you using?
- Are you getting any errors?

**Edit:** Okay, looking at your query examples. What data type is items.thumb? Varchar, Text? Is it not at all possible to query this table using another method than literal text matching? (e.g. ID number). Does this column have an index?